# Easier way to use plugins with the composition api in vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router, vuejs3, vue-i18n

When adding `vuex` or `vue-router` as plugin in vue and using the options api you could access these plugins with the `this` keyword.

**main.js**

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import i18n from '@/i18n';
import router from './router';
import store from './store';

app.use(i18n);
app.use(store);
app.use(router);
```

**RandomComponent.vue**

```
<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            this.$store.dispatch('roles/fetchPermissions');
        },
    }
</script>
```

The `this` keyword is no longer available with the composition api which leads to a lot of repetitive code. To use the `store`, `vue-router` or the `i18n` library I have to import and define the following:

**RandomComponent.vue with composition api**

```
<script setup>
    import { useStore } from 'vuex';
    import { useRouter } from 'vue-router';
    import { useI18n } from 'vue-i18n';

    const router = useRouter();
    const store = useStore();
    const { t } = useI18n();

    const { handleSubmit, isSubmitting, errors } = useForm('/roles/create', role, CreateRoleValidationSchema, () => {
        store.dispatch('notifications/addNotification', {
            type: 'success',
            title: t('create_success', { field: t('role', 1) }),
        });

        router.push({ name: 'roles' });
    });
</script>
```

Is there a way to avoid these imports and definitions and have a way to easily use these plugins like I could do with the options api?

Answer (score 5):

There is no built-in way of doing that in Composition API and script setup.

What you could do is:

#### Create a `plugins.js` file that exports common bindings you want to import. For example:

```js
export * from 'vuex'
export * from 'vue-router'
export * from 'vue-i18n'
```

And then you have only 1 import to do:

```html
<script setup>
    import { useStore, useRouter, useI18n } from './plugins'

    const router = useRouter();
    const store = useStore();
    const { t } = useI18n();

    const { handleSubmit, isSubmitting, errors } = useForm('/roles/create', role, CreateRoleValidationSchema, () => {
        store.dispatch('notifications/addNotification', {
            type: 'success',
            title: t('create_success', { field: t('role', 1) }),
        });

        router.push({ name: 'roles' });
    });
</script>
```

You can go even further by initiating the plugins like:

```js
import { useStore, useRouter, useI18n } from './plugins'

export function initiateCommonPlugins() {
    const router = useRouter();
    const store = useStore();
    const { t } = useI18n();

    return { router, store, t }
}
```

And your code then will look like this:

```html
<script setup>
    import { router, store, t } from './initiate-plugins'

    const { handleSubmit, isSubmitting, errors } = useForm('/roles/create', role, CreateRoleValidationSchema, () => {
        store.dispatch('notifications/addNotification', {
            type: 'success',
            title: t('create_success', { field: t('role', 1) }),
        });

        router.push({ name: 'roles' });
    });
</script>
```

#### Use [unplugin-auto-import](https://github.com/antfu/unplugin-auto-import) plugin

This plugin can eliminate all imports you want and is highly customizable. Haven't tried it yet but I have seen people recommend it.

#### Stick to Options API

Using Vue 3 doesn't mean that you have to use Composition API for creating components. You can use Options API along with `script setup` for composables instead of Mixins.
So Options API for components, Composition API for reusing code or advanced use-cases.

Comment: Kind of sad to see this syntax go, any reason they decided to go this route?

Comment: They aren't deprecating Options API, if that's what you meant by "let go". It kind of makes sense that Composition API is as raw as it is; for the people who care, they want that.